# MigraDoc Paragraph Text, possible to Truncate?

Tags: migradoc

The Paragraph in MigraDoc automatically wraps text and adjust the height automatically.  I want to be able to Truncate the text and if possible get it to Shrink to Fit.  Has anyone accomplished this or have any idea how to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use functions from PDFsharp to query the size of the text - and then reduce font size or shorten the text until it fits.

See also here:
http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=6158#p6158